# Get an update of another telegram channel using a telegram bot

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I implementing a telegram bot in c#. Now there is a basis, that is, the bot itself is created, the token is connected.

The question is how to make the bot receive updates of certain telegram channels? In particular, I am interested in the latest posts from each of the channels. For example: N channel has a new post, at this moment bot should get information from this post (text, photo/video (photo/video is optional) ) and then the bot will be able to process the received text. The bot is not the administrator of these channels and this is not provided for in the implementation. If the bot cannot be the channel administrator in this implementation, is it possible to add, for example, an intermediary who will receive updates and pass them to the bot? For example, could my personal Telegram account be the intermediary? If so, how can this be done? I've tried a bunch of different methods, but all of them are aimed at getting messages/updates specifically from the bot user and not from any other/foreign telegram channels.

I use Telegram.bot package. I'm willing to use any package, as long as it can be implemented.

I tried to use mostly only functions from the Telegram.bot package. Such as getUpdates, getChatMessages, getChatHistory and so on.
I found one, maybe the parameter of the method is channelPost. But I couldn't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score -2):

If you want your Telegram bot to receive updates from specific channels, you'll need to do a little workaround since the bot itself can't be an admin of those channels. Here's a casual way to approach it:

Create a separate Telegram account, like your personal account, and add it as an admin to the channels you're interested in.

Head over to the BotFather on Telegram and create a new bot. This will give you an API token to interact with the bot.

In your C# project, use the Telegram.Bot package and configure it with the API token from your newly created bot.

Now, using the Telegram.Bot package, listen for updates from your personal account. You can do this by calling the GetUpdatesAsync method, which retrieves new messages from the chat history of your personal account.

Once you receive updates, you can process them in your code and extract the relevant information, such as text, photos, or videos from the channel posts.

Remember that when you receive updates from your personal account, you'll get messages from all the channels that you're an admin of. You'll need to filter out and handle only the updates that come from the channels you're interested in, based on their chat IDs or other criteria.

Keep in mind that using an intermediary account has its limitations and considerations. There might be some delays, and you'll need to ensure your personal account stays active and connected to the channels. Also, be mindful of the Telegram Bot API's usage limits and guidelines.

So, by setting up this intermediary account and leveraging the Telegram.Bot package in C#, you can receive updates from Telegram channels

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Comment: But my personal account can't be the administrator of other people's Telegram channels, can it? By the way, a similar answer was given to me by chatGPT.

Comment: The answer seems to be chatGPT generated since being an admin already solves the question. Unfortunately, if you are not an admin, you can't do much. Try first parsing a web version to gather posts from the group you're interested in, and then posting the updates to bot. But you would need to have a browser window to be open all the time tho.